# XSD - how to define relationship between two elements

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd, jaxb

I have a XSD file like below:

```
<element name="finder-def" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <complexType>
         <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required"></attribute>
         <attribute name="description" type="string"></attribute>
         <attribute name="class" type="string" use="required"></attribute>
    </complexType>
</element>

<complexType name="Dimension">
    <sequence>
        <element name="finder" type="Finder" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Finder">
    <attribute name="name" type="String" use="required"/>
</complexType>
```

XML file corresponds to above XSD file is below:

```
<finder-def name="circleFinder" description="Finds circle based on msisdn" class="com.onmobile.reporting.etl.processor.common.propertyplugins.CircleIdPropertyPlugin" />

<dimension name="circleId">
    <finder name="circleFinder" />
</dimension>
```

So, here I have defined one `finder-def` i.e. `circleFinder` and then want to refer to this `finder-def` through `finder` element.

So the question is How can I validate that `finder` `circleFinder` has its defination defined above in `finder-def`

Comment: Provide a valid and compltete .xml and a valid and complete .xsd sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another way to use ID and IDREF types inside schema.
Example: 
Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:f="http://test.com/finder" xsi:schemaLocation="http://test.com/finder finder.xsd">

<f:finder-def name="circleFinder" description="Finds circle based on msisdn"
              class="com.onmobile.reporting.etl.processor.common.propertyplugins.CircleIdPropertyPlugin"/>

<f:dimension name="circleId">
    <f:finder name="circleFinder"/>
</f:dimension>
</f:root>
```

XSD schema (I've formatted it a bit to validate)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://test.com/finder"
        xmlns:tns="http://test.com/finder"
        elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="finder-def" type="tns:finder-def" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="dimension" type="tns:Dimension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="finder-def">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="class" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Dimension">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="finder" type="tns:Finder" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Finder">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:IDREF" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: @Viktor +1 - One problem in above approach is that now the java classes generated from the above XSD using JAXB has 'name' property of type 'Object' instead of 'String'. And I was using those generated classes at various places. So is there any other way for this?

Comment: +1 - For more information of JAXB and `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF` see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: Make "name" as of type string and add another elment "ref" of type IDREF. Also you can add an inner element of type IDREF for "finder" element and add an jaxb annotation to it xsd:annotation->xsd:appinfo->jaxb:property->jaxb:baseType value com.test.finder.finder-def so that element be of right type after xsd-java class generation.